# What db methods are available in Strapi v3 by default?

Tags: strapi

https://strapi.io/blog/using-database-transactions-to-write-queries-in-strapi?utm_source=dev.to&utm_medium=post&utm_id=blog

I read the documentation for v3, but it doesn't tell me what mongoose methods I have access to from the beginning, so I was wondering if there were any guide or documentation that told me how to access all the Mongoose methods for article for example?

I tried calling

```
strapi.services.article.findMany({
    offset: 10,
    limit: 10,
    where: {
        id: ctx.query.id
    }
})
```

But I got: strapi.services.article.findMany is not a function

It works if I do:

```
strapi.services.article.find(ctx.query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strapi provides a query API to interact with the database layer. Whether you're using mysql, postgres or mongodb, the API will have the same interface by definition (see [query API documentation](https://docs-v3.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization.html#queries)).

`find` is the way to go to find many entries.

PS: Since the article you posted is about database transaction with Strapi, I advise you to read my article about the [caveats to be aware of](https://basile-mousketon.com/strapi-and-database-transactions-the-right-way/).